# Modify information in Google Sheet Cell based on information in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need help.  I have a spreadsheet that has street addresses with the city compressed behind the street address.

(Example:  A1:  123 Flowers StreetRichmond )

I have the city in the adjacent col.

(Example:  B1:  Richmond )

I need a script that will reference the city name in B1 and give me the street address in Column  C without the city.

(Example:  C1:  123 Flowers Street )

Can this be done?

One last Challenge. I need it to recognize the city name regardless of case.  I have some in ALL CAPS and some in Title Case (Example:  RICHMOND or Richmond)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome. "Can this be done?" Absolutely. Would you outline the research that you did  before you posted your question?

Comment: @Tedinoz - I researched the "IFError" and "Search" functions to find the text in the cell but was unable to get the function to return the cells minus the city (Richmond).  I also researched the All Caps vs Title Case issue.  I found the =Proper(text) function will work great in converting the text but if the city is adjacent to the street address without a space then the city is left as all lowercase with the last word of the street.  So in my example it would show up as Streetrichmond.

Comment: This is the formula I am using in C1 but it keeps giving me an error 
 =IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(B1,A1,1),A1-B1,"No"))

Comment: You said "I need a script". Did you mean this literally, or as a custom function, or, just not sure? –

Comment: Thank you @Tedinoz for asking for clarification.  I wasn't sure what was the best way to tackle my issue.  It turns out your help with a function turned out to be the answer.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for summarizing your research and for providing the formula that you tried. This is valuable information for a reader and, next time round, I hope that you will include this kind of information in the body of the question. Questioners want as many readers as possible to consider their question and maybe help with an answer. And readers like to understand the scenario, and be confident that the questioner made an effort to resolve/understand their own problem. See you round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `=left(A1,search(B1,A1)-1)`

---

Breakdown

- `search(B1,A1)`: this searches for the city (B1) in the full address (A1). SEARCH is case-insensitive, so the case of B1 is irrelevant.
  Based on the test data of "123 Flowers StreetRichmond", this search returns 19.
- `=left(A1,search(B1,A1)-1)`: we know that the city is at the end of the string in A1, so we use "LEFT" to return the characters up to, but excluding the Search value (you have deduct 1 to get only 18 characters).
  Based on the test data, the first 18 characters = "123 Flowers Street"

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thank you.  Also thank you for breaking this down - makes sense and helped me understand it better.